# changing editText to textView error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

Beginner at android, I did some research and did not come up with an answer - so I am posting on SO. Please keep in mind I have done the usual things such as going to javadoc or other first step problem solutions that most programmers do before asking another programmer for help. Basically, I am trying to learn how to send data between activities, and I understand how to send a message that someone types in (`editText`), but if I just want to send over data from a `textView`, this is where I am having issues. My question: what am i doing wrong on this line (I assume my syntax is wrong here, I don't feel the need to post rest of code, but will if it will help).

All I did was switch up "editText1" and "textView1" and although there's no errors in the code, whenever I run the app (the activity switch happens at a button press) and press the button it gives me an android error and closes the app.

```
//doesnt work
String text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();

//works
String text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are casting the `Textview` object  to `EditText` that two are different class

```
android.widget.TextView
android.widget.EditText
```

Comment: So instead of EditText, I can put TextView? (I tried looking all over android troubleshoot NEVER saw this!) Thank you if this is the answer.

Comment: thank you! works, I have another question now though, what class can I import that will handle an image? Also, what would be the syntax for that (considering I can't do .getText().toString()? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For image you need to use the ImageView

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. A piece of advice, always post crash logs when you are having some trouble with crashes. As per the very few pieces of info that you have provided, it seems that you must be getting a `ClassCastException` because you are trying to cast a `TextView`(textView1) to an `EditText` (editText1). The correct code would be

```
String text = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help sir, in the future I will try to post crash logs (don't know what those are, but will look them up in the future to grab them to help you guys help me out!). I did get my question answered though, i really appreciate you taking the time out to help though.

Answer (score 1):

A request to you as you are new.. Please check the respective `id` of  the `view` you used in 
your layout and make sure you are linking to corresponding `view` with there respective `id`.

In your case use :

```
String text_textview = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
```

and

```
String text_edittext = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
```

Thank you :)